# Notation on Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading [Naive Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614271313).

On Section 3 (Unordered Pairs), page 11, it is written that:

> As further examples, we note that
>   $$\{x:x\neq x\} = \varnothing$$
>   and
>   $$\{x:x= a\} = \{a\}.$$
>   In case $S(x)$ is $(x \in' x)$, or in case $S(x)$ is $(x=x)$, the specified $x$'s do not constitute a set.

The last sentence is not clear to me. Is it because, if $S(x)$ is $(x=x)$, this denotes the set with whichever $x$ I can imagine? But what happens in the first case, i.e. if $S(x)$ is $(x \notin x)$?

Comment: Have you ever heard of Russel's Paradox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that $A=\{x: x\notin x\}$ is a set.

Then, is $A\in A$ a true statement? How about $A\notin A$?

Comment: If $A \in A$ then $A \notin A$, if $A \notin A$ then $A \in A$. So should I conclude that it is impossible to create a set with this $S(x)$?

Comment: @fbrundu Indeed. The premise must be wrong, and the only premise was that $A$ is a set.

Answer (score 1):

That complication is a part of what I should call non-naive set theory. The reason these doesn't constitute sets is to avoid Russel's paradox.

We simply has to put restrictions in order to avoid statements similar to "this statement is false".

It's obvious how one could formulate such a statement if we allowed a set like $A = \{x: x\notin x\}$, since then $A\in A$ would be such a statement.