# Why $\{x: x = x\}$ is not a set in Naive Set Theory? (Halmos, Sec. 4)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading [Naive Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614271313) by Paul Halmos.

> On Section 3 (Unordered Pairs), page 11, it is written that:
>
> > As further examples, we note that $$\{x:x\neq x\} = \varnothing$$ and $$\{x:x= a\} = \{a\}.$$ In case $S(x)$ is $(x \in' x)$, or in case
> >     $S(x)$ is $(x=x)$, the specified $x$'s do not constitute a set.

I understood that the problem with the existence of a set specified as
$\{x:x \notin x\}$ is that if such a set $A$ exists, the statement $A \in A$ can be proven to be both true and false sentence.

Still I can't understand why can't we specify a set of elements specified by a sentence $\{x: x = x\}$.

PS. This is a cite of a SE Math question [Notation on Set Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618196/notation-on-set-theory). I quoted the original question and explicitly stated that part of it which was obvious to the original author, but I can't understand his explanation:

> The last sentence is not clear to me. Is it because, if $S(x)$ is
>   $(x=x)$, this denotes the set with whichever $x$ I can imagine?

that also seems to be stated as a suggestion and not as a final answer.

Comment: See [Russell's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/) and [Universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set) : "Russell's paradox prevents the existence of a *universal set* in Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory and other set theories that include Zermelo's axiom of comprehension. This axiom states that, for any formula $\varphi (x)$ and any set $A$, there exists another set $\{ x\in A \mid \varphi (x) \}$
that contains exactly those elements $x$ of $A$ that satisfy $\varphi$.

Comment: ... If a universal set $V$ existed and the axiom of comprehension could be applied to it, then there would also exist another set $\{ x\in V \mid x \not \in x \}$, the set of all sets that do not contain themselves."

Comment: Specification allows us to "cut-off" from an existsing set $A$ the subset of those $x \in A$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds of them. Thus, it is perfectly fine to use it to define the set $\{ x \in A \mid x=x \}$, but this is not the "universal set" $V$ but only a subset of an already existing set $A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thank you for the explanations. It took a lot of time to answer because I thought I could understand both explanations, my own question and the logic of Halmos' explanations (excuse me a pun) which is the source of it all. Actually I'm still not able to understand the latter

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, two points I can make:
1) your explanation is clear. I understood your point (that a set must be specified when we use the axiom of specification) when I was reading Halmos (and my understanding of set theory is based on his book). So I guess in that place he's just a bit breve in notation (suddenly starting to use just formulas without the sets for elements to be specified from) and that brevity produces questions which are useful and let a student like me to explore the subject but it's still hard and maybe unnecessary to address the brevity of one his paragraph itself.

Comment: Step 1: start from [Axioms of set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) and specifically from *Separation* (I'll simplify it a little bit) : $∀w ∃v ∀r(r∈v ↔ r∈w ∧ \psi(r))$ that reads : "let $\psi$ a formula and let $w$ a set : there exists a set $v$ which has as members precisely the members of $w$ which satisfy the formula $\psi$." This means that we must have the formula $\psi$ **and** and already existing set $w$ in order to "carve out" from $w$ its subset $v$ of all and only those $r \in w$ such that $\psi(r)$ holds.

Comment: Thus, using $r=r$ as $\psi(r)$, the axiom (schema) does not license the assertion : $∃v∀r(r∈v↔r=r)$ because it is missing the "already given" set $w$. What we can do is the innocuous $∀w∃v∀r(r∈v↔r∈w∧ r=r)$ that correctly (and trivially) define the subset $v$ of $w$ of all and only those $r \in w$ such that $r=r$ holds. But $r=r$ holds of every member of $w$, and thus $v=w$.

Comment: Then we have another thread : the so-called Russell's set : $\{ x : x \notin x \}$ cannot exists in a "good" set theory, because if we assume its existence, we can easily derive a contradiction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, the second point I wanted to make is that: may it be the goal of Halmos' introductory text to give some intuition, notions of set theory and axiomatic approach, get a student used to the strict notation and abstractness of the whole subject. So maybe inexperienced student should just benefit from that and then (if needed) get to a more solid or axiomatic-based text? 
sorry for interrupting, I understood the (simplified) step 1 and will soon check the argument that follows!

Comment: The last step is the proof that $V = \{ x : x=x \}$ does not exists; up to now, we have only showed that we cannot use *Separation* to proved its existence. But we may expect to "have it" in some other ways... This is not, because **if** we assume that $V$ exists, we can use it with *Separation* to build : $∃v∀r(r∈v↔r∈V∧ r \notin r)$. Here $r \notin r$ is a "correct" formula $\psi(r)$ and **if** $V$ exists, then the previous is a correct instance of the axiom (schema). But then, accordin to the axiom, we have that $(r \in ↔ r \notin r)$ and thus $v$ is the Russell's set.

Comment: But we have shown that the Ruseel's set cannot exsts, and thus also the set $V$ cannot exists, and thus we cannot use it in any instance of *Separation*.

Comment: See [Halmos](https://books.google.it/books?id=jV_aBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), *Preface*, page v : "The present treatment might best be described as axiomatic set theory from the naive point of view. It is axiomatic in that some axioms for s.t. are stated and used [...]. It is naive in that the language and notation are those of ordinary informal (but formalizable) mathematics." Perhaps the experiment has not worked in full...

Comment: Set theory is a little bit "tricky" : the theory "speaks" about *sets*. What are sets? from the point of view of an axiomatized theory, sets are those "objects" that satisfy the axioms of the theory. What "kind of sets" exists ? Those whose existence we can prove using the axioms. We start with the *Null set* Ax asserting that in the "universe of discourse" of our theory there is the "emptyset" : $\emptyset$. An then ? We can use *Separation* to "curve out" from it a subset according to a formula $\psi$... Ok, but subset of $\emptyset$ are still $\emptyset$: so, uo to now, no new sets.

Comment: And then enters: *Pairs, Power set, Union, Infinity*, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with you that [Halmos](https://books.google.it/books?id=jV_aBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)'s sentence (page 11) :

> In case $S(x)$ is $(x∈′x)$, or in case $S(x)$ is $(x=x)$, the specified $x$'s do not constitute a set.

is not crystal clear.

Halmos has introduced the *Specification axiom* ([page 6](https://books.google.it/books?id=jV_aBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6)):

> for every $A$ and condition$S(x)$ the set $B$ whose elements... witten $B= \{ x \in A : S(x) \}$ exists.

Then (same page) he proves, using the construction of Russell's paradox, that there is no "universal" set; i.e. he proves that:

> for every set $A$, there is a set $B$ such that $B \in' A$,

specifically, this set is $B = \{ x \in A : x \in ' x \}$.

*Comment*: here the definition of $B$ is correct, according to *Specification*. What we have to note is that, up to now (page 6), we do not know if there are sets at all.

*Specification* is a "conditional" set existence axiom: if we have a set $A$, the axiom licences us to build new sets (subsets of $A$) for every "specifiable" condition $S(x)$.

Then (page 8) we start populating the "universe" of sets, with the "temporary" axiom:

> there exists a set.

In other axiomatization of the theory, the first "existential axiom" is usually the [Empty set axiom](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/#AxiZFC).

In Halmos approach, the existence of the empty set is proved: let $A_0$ the set whose existence has been asserted by the above axiom; then, by *Specification*, we have that:

> $\{ x \in A_0 : x \ne x \}$

exists. Clearly, this set is empty, and by *Extensionality* we have that it is unique (i.e. two empty sets must coincide) and thus we call it **the** emptyset : $\emptyset$.

Third axiom (page 9) : *Pairing*. Again, it is "conditional" : for any two sets $a, b$ there exists a set that they both belong to :

> for every $a,b$, the set $A = \{ x = a \text { or } x = b \}$ exists;

or: $x \in A \text { iff } x = a \text { or } x = b$. Call it $\{ a, b \}$.

*Comment* : again, up to now we know only of $\emptyset$. Thus, applying *Pair* to it, what we get is nothing more than $\{ \emptyset \}$, and so on.

In general (page 10), *Pair* applied to $a$ only (instead of : $a,b$) gives us $\{ a \}$ for every set $a$.

And now we have the comments of page 10 (last half) and page 11: .

We know that $\{ x : S(x) \}$ is not a correct way to create sets.

In spite of this, Halmos consider some "good" cases :

> *(i)* let $S(x)$ the formula $x \in A$.

In this case, the "bad" $\{ x : S(x) \}$ works, because it amounts to :

> $\{ x : x \in A \} = \{ x \in A : x \in A \}=A$

and this is a legitimate instance of *Specification*.

*Comment* : of course, it is only a "typographical" usage because we cannot use it to prove nothing new. The set $A$ is "already there".

> *(ii)* The same with $x \ne x$ as $S(x)$.

We have that:

> for every $A$ : $\{ x \in A : x \ne x \} = \emptyset$

exists, by *Specification*. In this way, we have "specified" the empty subset of every set $A$; but by *extensionality* they all coincide, and thus we do not care about $A$.

*Comment* : maybe the "standard" approach of postulating directly the existence of $\emptyset$ is better...

> *(iii)* Also the "wrong" $\{ x : x = a \}$ does not harm.

It is only a shorthand for the set $\{ x : x = a \text { or } x = a \}$ licensed by *Pairing*.

And here we stop...

Two further cases of $S(x)$ :

> $(x \in ' x)$ and $(x=x)$

cannot be used, because they lead to problems (discussed above).

*I hope it may help*.

Answer (score 3):

If $V=\{x:x=x\}$ is a set, then by specification, $\{x:x\notin x\}$ is also a set, since every $x=x$, so $\{x:x\notin x\}=\{x\in V:x\notin x\}$. Of course, this is impossible.

It should be noted that there are set theories with a universal set, but they resolve the problem of Russell's paradox in a different way. One such set theory is Quine's New Foundations.

Comment: Thank you, so if I understood yours and Mauro's explanation correctly, the mentioned in the text $\{x:x=x\}$ is not a specification of some set $A$ by the axiom of specification, i.e. it shouldn't be read as "for some set $A$ those elements $x$ of $A$ that satisfy $x = x$". Instead, it's implicitly using the reflexiveness of the equality relation and thus implies the existence of the Universal set.